# SQL: Count each row value in a column and return count into multiple column

Tags: sql

From this table

```
D_value
-------
A 
B 
B 
C 
C 
C
```

To display count `D_Value` into this table

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 2 | 3
```

Comment: How many different values do you expect?

Comment: why cant you do it with traditional way (row per value, count pair): `select D_value, count(*) from table group by D_value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a single row, use this.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(CASE WHEN D_Value = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS A,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN D_Value = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS B,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN D_Value = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS C
FROM
   MyTable
```

This works for a finite and fixed number of values to count

If you do not know how many different values, then you need to do a simple aggregate and make a single row in the client code.

```
SELECT D_value, COUNT(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY D_value;
```

However, this won't give zero counts for values that do not exist. So you'd need a lookup table and LEFT JOIN. I won't go there yet...

Answer (score 0):

```
select D_value,count(*) from table group by D_value;
```

Comment: That will be row wise OP asked for column wise.